# Current best practice/methods to code a VB.NET DAL in SQL Server

Tags: junior-programmer

What are the current best practice/methods to code a VB.NET DAL in SQL Server?

I have been trying to search but can't seem to find the right words to look for.

Comment: A. Why would the answer be VB-specific, the same should apply for any .NET language. B. Why VB? In any .NET app you could include any .NET assembly, so don't limit yourself to the "basics".

Comment: @DannyVarod I agree 100% with you. But this is what my employer wants so I just needed to be specific haha

Comment: I wouldn't say there is a general best practice. Choose a technology (or examine a few) and then ask about different practices for that technology. (E.g. Entity Framework, nHibernate, DataSets, 3rd party ORMs and etc.)

Comment: Probably something like Entity Framework with the Repository pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the term you're looking for is ORM (Object Relational Mapping).

Entity Framework is an ORM framework. I would just add that LINQ is a standalone framework that can be used to query data, SQL, Entity Framework or even an XML file, so they are not exactly interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ-To-SQL or Entity Framework.

Entity Framework is the most current and tends to enforce better design practices but can be overkill for some projects and may not be the best option for some types of underlying data.

LINQ-To-SQL is easy to use and will fit into most projects rather easily. On the downside, it can be misused more easily than EF.

Comment: LINQ to SQL was declared as and end of the road technology prior to release of EF1. Therefore I would most definitely **not** recommend it as a **best practice**.

Comment: @DannyVarod - Microsoft has a nasty tendency to obsolete things too quickly that still work well and replacing them with half-loaf implementations (like EF1). I predict EF will be declared "dead" in late 2012-early 2013 in favor of a poorly implemented NoSQL/BigData style framework.

Comment: I think they would have to create a NoSQL Server first for the NoEF to connect to :-)